# Numpy multidimensional arrays and inverse accessing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array with rank=4. Suppose it looks like this:

```
np.shape(my_array)
(10,5,25,50)
```

I also have a list of 10 values, such as

```
x = np.arange(10)
```

I would like to be able to plot `x` against the first axis of `my_array` for every value, that is, I would like to do:

```
for axis2_index in xrange(5):
    for axis3_index in xrange(25):
        for axis4_index in xrange(50):
            plt.plot(x,my_array[:,axis2_index,axis3_index,axis4_index])
```

But of course, I want to do that in a numpy form, without `for` loops. I have been struggling with that for quite long, but still can't find any easy way to do it.

To put it differently, I would like to be able to access `my_array` that I could, for example, get an array of 5x25x50 vectors of 10 each, these corresponding to the first axis in `my_array`. I also tried `np.reshape`, but it changes the order of the elements in such a way that I cannot use it.

Comment: Isn't this a very large number of lines? In this case, it is not the speed of the for-loops that you need to worry about, but the rendering speed. However, I would suggest you look up `np.broadcast_arrays`.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant. This is just an example, and I would actually like to do some computations and accessing with all these numbers: they are the result of computing a function on a grid of 3 different parameters, and the extra dimension is the output of the function, which itself is an array (a spectrum). I have checked `np.broadcast_arrays`, but still can't see how I could use that.. any tutorial with a similar case that I could look at? the numpy doc was not enough for me to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using broadcasting:

```
y = randn(10,4)
x = arange(10)

plot(x[:,None],y)
```

I guess in your case you would have `x[:,None,None,None]`.

Comment: That was my initial attempt when you mentioned broadcasting, but the following error comes out `ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I'll get back to you. You'll have to reshape to 2d: the first dimension the independent axis, and the rest for all the other parameters.

Comment: I managed to get to it through an intricate command: `my_array.transpose().reshape(5*25*50,10)`and then simply plot each element of that against `x`. But that losses the information on the coordinates (param1,param2,and param3) values for each model I think, so not really very useful...

Comment: So you have one line for each parameter combination; how would you like this to be displayed?

Comment: Actually that is a very good point :) This reshaping allows to plot it quite easily, but I was hoping to find and "easy" way to tell to which parameters each of those arrays corresponds to. It could very well be that I just misused `numpy` here.